# Hierarchy of model file lookup?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I asked Brian this yesterday, but we couldn't figure it out by memory.  What is the order of operations that Gazebo looks for files?  Let's say there is a model file on my local machine and also a model file in the model database online, where does Gazebo go to look for the files?  It seems like Gazebo is always trying to go online to download models, even if I have them stored locally.  I'd like to know how to work around this, for times that I'm not online, and to manually enforce a particular model repository.  This probably plays in with the difference between a  call and a  call.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2973/hierarchy-of-model-file-lookup?/) by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The < uri > tags are resolved by [gazebo::common::SystemPaths::FindFileUri](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d18b006ad83d62e0325f279bc909de9a48d2aa79/gazebo/common/SystemPaths.cc?at=default#cl-252), which iterates in order through the `modelPaths` list. This list is constructed with `$HOME/.gazebo/models` at the beginning followed by the paths listed in the `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` environment variable (see [SystemPaths::UpdateModelPaths](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d18b006ad83d62e0325f279bc909de9a48d2aa79/gazebo/common/SystemPaths.cc?at=default#cl-136)).

So if you have a model in `~/.gazebo/models`, it will always take that one. If not, it will look through the rest of your model path, and eventually try to download it if it can't find it locally.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0